# Traefik dasboard not working with subdomain

Tags: traefik

I am trying to setup Traefik dashboard under a subdomain, but I am getting 404 page not found. However, I can access the api without any problems. Below is the docker-compose.yml that I have created.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9.6
    container_name: traefik
    hostname: traefik
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.debug=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefikweb
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefikweb
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=dashboard@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web
networks:
  traefikweb:
    external: true
```

I need guidance what I am doing wrong and why traefik.example.com/api/rawdata works and traefik.example.com/dashboard won't. Thanks

**My solution based on larsks answer:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9.6
    container_name: traefik
    hostname: traefik
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.debug=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefikweb
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
      - --accessLog.filePath=/dev/stderr
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefikweb
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=dashboard@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=web

      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web

networks:
  traefikweb:
    external: true
```

Usage:

http://traefik.example.com -> will take you to dashboard

http://traefik.example.com/api/rawdata -> will take you to api

I have also removed port forwarding 8080:8080. So only way to access the api is through the url http://traefik.example.com/api/...

This is my first step towards dashboard and api routing. **Next step is to secure it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been poking at this for a bit and the following configuration works for me. This exposes the dashboard at `http://traefik.internal/dashboard` and the API at `http://traefik.internal/api`.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9.6
    container_name: traefik
    hostname: traefik
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.debug=true
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefikweb
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --accessLog.filePath=/dev/stderr
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefikweb
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.internal`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web

      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.internal`) && PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=dashboard@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=web

      # configure stripprefix rule for the dashboard
      - traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=dashboard-stripprefix
      - traefik.http.middlewares.dashboard-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/dashboard
networks:
  traefikweb:
    external: true
```

Comment: Yes, with the port it works. What's not working is traefik.example.com/dashboard. However, traefik.example.com/api/http/routers does work. Also, thank you for suggesting to use the address with the port 8080 (I didn't know that)

Comment: I've updated this answer with a configuration that seems to work as intended.

Comment: Thanks. It works by providing a slash at the end like: /dashboard/